# Bootstrapx clickover issue - Two clicks needed and sometimes 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm experiencing issues with Bootstrapx clickover (all js libraries are correctly linked)

```
   $(function ()  { 
    $('.userProfile').each(function(index){
        var el=$(this);
        $.get(el.attr('data-load'),function(d){
            el.clickover({html:true,content: d}).clickover();                   
        });
    }); 

   });
```

**And my html**

```
<p><a href="#" class="userProfile" rel="clickover" data-load="inc/userProfile.inc">
```

Alex m. completed a mission for Marc B.

**Popover content**

```
<a href="#">Alex M.</a>
<span class="label">Volunteer</span>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-small">Follow</button>
<button class="btn btn-small" data-toggle="button" data-dismiss="clickover">Close</button>
```

Looking forward to getting some help,

Thanks,

Isabelle,

Comment: what issues? please divulge further

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are forced to use

```
el.clickover({html:true,content: d}).clickover();
```

instead of

```
el.clickover({html:true,content: d});
```

Can you reproduce it on a pastebin?